# colabで作成したフォルダをダウンロードしたい

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

google colab上でスクレイピングを行い、画像を収集したフォルダをローカルpcにダウンロードしたいです。ファイル一つ一つのダウンロードはfiles.download()でできるのですが、まとめてフォルダごとダウンロードする方法が分かりませんので教えていただきたいです

Answer (score 0):

この記事によると承認は付いていませんが、.zipや.tarのファイルにしてそれをダウンロードすることで出来るようです。
元記事 [How do I download multiple files or an entire folder from Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50453428/9014308) / 翻訳 [python 3.x - Google Colabから複数のファイルまたはフォルダー全体をダウンロードするにはどうすればよいですか？](https://tutorialmore.com/questions-681101.htm)
この回答が簡潔でしょうか。

> I have created a zip file:
>
> ```
> !zip -r /content/file.zip /content/Folder_To_Zip
> ```
>
> Than I have downloded that zip file:
>
> ```
> from google.colab import files
> files.download("/content/file.zip")
> ```

サブフォルダが不要なら、こちらの`for`ループでも出来るようです。
[Google Colaboratoryでフォルダ内のファイルを一括ダウンロード](http://hihan.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/01/04/031825)

その他参考：
[GoogleDriveとColaboratory間のデータ操作まとめ PyDrive](https://qiita.com/Hyperion13fleet/items/14a4f9ff1a41a3ab0301)
[Colaboratoryのデータの入出力まとめ](https://qiita.com/5at00001040/items/d7867974d2fd1d21dbbf)